# how can display arabic characters in cmd?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, cmd.exe, arabic

i found answers to use active codes like 1256 or 16001 but the characters appeared in different form, Anyone can help me display arabic characters in cmd?

Wrong characters example:

[image]